# Shell wild card to select n files with same naming scheme?

Tags: regex, shell, terminal

**Given n files**

```
SRTM_W_250m_TIF.tif
SRTM_SE_250m_TIF.tif
SRTM_NE_250m_TIF.tif
```

**with same naming scheme, something like :**

```
SRTM_*_250_TIF.tif
```

In linux Shell, **what is the wild card / regex, in order to use to select these n files ?**

---

Note: I wish to replace :

```
gdal_merge.py -o World_SRTM4.tif SRTM_W_250m_TIF.tif SRTM_SE_250m_TIF.tif SRTM_NE_250m_TIF.tif
```

by something more generic since I now got 872 files to process. **What should be ma command?**

Comment: `gdal_merge.py` is used to merge a specific kind of files. I wan merge n of these files into `World_SRTM4.tif`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern you posted should work fine:

```
gdal_merge.py -o World_SRTM4.tif SRTM_*_250m_TIF.tif
```

Comment: Oh. `*` is by default a regex and should be escaped to be the `*` simple character... Makes sense.

Comment: @Hugolpz, that is a shell ["filename expansion pattern"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion), otherwise knows as a "glob pattern".